# ProPublica API key in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get the json from the ProPublica Congress API. I have a key but don't know how to send it in java. The only example in the documentation is this:

```
curl "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/115/senate/members.json"
-H "X-API-Key: PROPUBLICA_API_KEY"
```

I've tried variations of this with no luck:

```
URL url = new URL("https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/115/senate/members.json");
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("X-API-Key:", "PROPUBLICA_API_KEY");
InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who is wondering you can look at this project here:
https://github.com/konklone/congress-android

Thanks to Eric Mill, creator of the Congress app, and to Derek at ProPublica support.